# Which principal does PrincipalPermission.Demand() check against?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have some code in a general library that does authorization checking like this

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);    
new PrincipalPermission(null, "AD_GROUP_NAME").Demand();
```

I'm having some issues when it's called from inside a 3rd party job scheduling framework. The check fails. I've tried figuring out why.
When I check the value of `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` it is one user (UserA) and when I check `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` it's a different user (UserB). Both users should have the correct access so it shouldn't fail.
I suspect that it's checking against something other than these two.

I've made a small test program that only does the check. I've used the `Runas` command to run it with both UserA and UserB and both pass the check when I do it that way.

I'd love some help figuring out how to get it to work.

Update: I'm pretty sure that the check is done against `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` (ie. UserB). When I debug, I can see that the principal is a ClaimsPrincipal and not a WindowsPrincipal. I assume that the `SetPrincipalPolicy` call doesn't have an effect. The documentation seems to hint that the call needs to be done becore the thread is created and it isn't. The 3rd party framework sets up the thread before it reaches my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` wasen't a Windows principal.

I added some code to set the principal to a new WindowsPrincipal based on `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. After I made the authorization check, I restored the principal to the previous value like this

```
var savedPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
try
{
     Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());

     // Call the code that does the authorization check
}
finally
{
     Thread.CurrentPrincipal = savedPrincipal;
}
```

This also does the check against UserA's rights which is what I would prefer.